# How to loop over columns containing NA values? R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, na

I have the following data which is looks like this:

```
  2010-11-04 to 2010-11-10 2010-11-11 to 2010-11-17 2010-11-18 to 2010-11-24 2010-11-26 to 2010-12-02
 [1,] "Stock194"               "Stock194"               NA                       "Stock241"              
 [2,] "Stock26"                "Stock217"               NA                       "Stock440"              
 [3,] "Stock314"               "Stock241"               NA                       "Stock485"              
 [4,] "Stock334"               "Stock321"               NA                       "Stock57"               
 [5,] "Stock453"               "Stock334"               NA                       "Stock77"               
 [6,] "Stock62"                "Stock39"                NA                       NA                      
 [7,] NA                       "Stock391"               NA                       NA                      
 [8,] NA                       "Stock430"               NA                       NA                      
 [9,] NA                       "Stock444"               NA                       NA                      
[10,] NA                       "Stock453"               NA                       NA                      
[11,] NA                       "Stock485"               NA                       NA                      
[12,] NA                       "Stock62"                NA                       NA                      
[13,] NA                       "Stock76"                NA                       NA                      
[14,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[15,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[16,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[17,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[18,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[19,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[20,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[21,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
[22,] NA                       NA                       NA                       NA                      
      2010-12-03 to 2010-12-09
 [1,] "Stock12"               
 [2,] "Stock217"              
 [3,] "Stock321"              
 [4,] "Stock334"              
 [5,] "Stock39"               
 [6,] "Stock391"              
 [7,] "Stock453"              
 [8,] "Stock464"              
 [9,] "Stock485"              
[10,] "Stock62"               
[11,] "Stock76"               
[12,] NA                      
[13,] NA                      
[14,] NA                      
[15,] NA                      
[16,] NA                      
[17,] NA                      
[18,] NA                      
[19,] NA                      
[20,] NA                      
[21,] NA                      
[22,] NA
```

.

```
> dput(a)
structure(c("Stock194", "Stock26", "Stock314", "Stock334", "Stock453", 
"Stock62", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Stock194", "Stock217", "Stock241", "Stock321", "Stock334", 
"Stock39", "Stock391", "Stock430", "Stock444", "Stock453", "Stock485", 
"Stock62", "Stock76", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Stock241", "Stock440", "Stock485", "Stock57", 
"Stock77", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Stock12", "Stock217", "Stock321", "Stock334", 
"Stock39", "Stock391", "Stock453", "Stock464", "Stock485", "Stock62", 
"Stock76", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(22L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2010-11-04 to 2010-11-10", "2010-11-11 to 2010-11-17", 
"2010-11-18 to 2010-11-24", "2010-11-26 to 2010-12-02", "2010-12-03 to 2010-12-09"
)))
>
```

i also have a loop which looks like this :

```
for (i in names(results2)) {
input <- i

# other steps and calculations 

}
```

What i need the loop to do is for example in the first step grab the entire column rows 1 to n and put it into input - including the NA values.

the issue is that for some reason names(results2) does not read the column. I think it's because of the fact that NA values are there but i am not sure.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If you ask me, your main problem are the bad column names. I would check out the `make.names` function.

Comment: There are no `names()` that function is for data frames. For matrices like yours try `colnames`

Comment: I'd recommend `for (i in seq(ncol(a))){iname <- colnames(a)[i]; icol <- a[, i]; ...}`. Looping over the names is a bad/dangerous practice with matrices, since there's nothing preventing names from repeating. E.g., `matrix(1:4,2,dimnames=list(c(1,1),c(2,2)))`. As a general rule, iterate over iterators, not over values.

Comment: @PierreLafortune i did already and it only returns the actual name of the column instead of the column itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is loop over each column.  Access your matrix by index instead of by name.

```
for (i in (1:ncol(results2))) {
 input <- results2[,i]   
 # other steps and calculations 
}
```

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the column names, as your columns have valid and unique names.  That being the case, you could access by name if you wanted, tho as @Frank has mentioned that can be unstable.

```
for (i in colnames(results2)) {
 input <- results2[,i]   
 # other steps and calculations 
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting: contrary to the OP's guess, their problem had nothing to do with `NA`s; this should solve it.